# Google tag manager not firing

Tags: https, get, google-tag-manager

my GTM pixels not firing / or not getting right response (on three websites, different GTM numbers of course)

this is what I see in a console:

```
GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-xxxxxxx net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
(anonymous) @ (index):109
(anonymous) @ (index):110
```

when I try to go to the address:
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='...

I see "site not secure" error messages, is it connected somehow?

GTM was working properly even few days ago, I have Google Analytics there and cookieYes scripts

Comment: please explain more about your settings and how you have set your GTM to get connected to analytics.google

Comment: it looks the problem does not occur any more..
https://www.googletagmanager.com was getting HTTPS error, like the certificate is not valid, but all seems ok now.
thanks